# .NET MAUI Hostname "..." not verified error for android app

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, maui

I get ssl error when requesting from maui android application, I tried bypass and similar methods but it didn't work

```
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    var data = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   var url = "url"; 
   HttpClientHandler handler = new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler();
   handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
   handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

                    ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol &= ~SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;


                    var response = await client.PostAsync(url , data);

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<responsecls>(responseBody);
                    responsecls responseobj = new responsecls();
                    responseobj = myobj;
```

Comment: what is "ssl error" **specifically**?  Please provide the **exact** error or exception message as well as the line that causes it.

Comment: System.Net.WebException: Hostname url not verified:
    certificate: sha...
    DN: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=TR

Comment: Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname url not verified:
    certificate: sha...
    DN: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=TR

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70434

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jason I allready try that but not worked

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by adding this in my **MainActivity.cs** file

Note that it is the HttpsURLConnection class from Java

```
using Javax.Net.Ssl;        

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
    #if DEBUG
            HttpsURLConnection.DefaultHostnameVerifier = new AllowAllHostnameVerifier();
    #endif
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
```